# Trying to use fake JSON data, but not able to update in HTML page

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, angular-services

The data is been displayed but I don't know why I'm not able to get the images as per the syntax and code.

[image: The data is been displayed but I don't know why I'm not able to get the images as per the syntax and code]

```
<h2>Amazing Places on Earth</h2>


<div class="card">
    <div class=" card-block">
        <img src="{{post.url}}" class="img-fluid ${3|rounded-top,rounded-right,rounded-bottom,rounded-left,rounded-circle,|}" style="width :300px" alt="paris">
        <div class="card-titile">
            {{post.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
            <p>Get details Click find more</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class=" btn btn-success"> Find More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML using bootstrap 4 code so far I have used in my component.

**please find the (get) request code below.** Also I'm using Angular's latest version

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-places',
  templateUrl: './places.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./places.component.css']
})
export class PlacesComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor(private data: PhotodataService) { }
  posts: object;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getdata().subscribe(data => {
      this.posts = data;
      console.log(this.posts);
    });
  }    
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are trying to iterate your posts array, you seem to be missing https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf in your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to iterate it with `*ngFor`

```
 <h2>Amazing Places on Earth</h2>
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <div class=" card-block">
            <img src="{{post.url}}" class="img-fluid ${3|rounded-top,rounded-right,rounded-bottom,rounded-left,rounded-circle,|}" style="width :300px" alt="paris">
            <div class="card-titile">
                {{post.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
                <p>Get details Click find more</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class=" btn btn-success"> Find More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) from your component

```html
<!-- notice the *ngFor below -->
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="card">
    <div class=" card-block">
        <img src="{{post.url}}" class="img-fluid ${3|rounded-top,rounded-right,rounded-bottom,rounded-left,rounded-circle,|}" style="width :300px" alt="paris">
        <div class="card-titile">
            {{post.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
            <p>Get details Click find more</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class=" btn btn-success"> Find More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

basically what this means is loop over all `posts` and create a `card` for each post

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use `*ngFor` in your `card` div to iterate over all posts and print url and title of each post.

Working demo added below.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfkjoj)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to loop over the JSON data with ***ngFor** plus use angular input binding for assigning src field of the image with **[src]** so your edited code will look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="card">
<div class=" card-block">
    <img [src]="post.url" class="img-fluid ${3|rounded-top,rounded-right,rounded-bottom,rounded-left,rounded-circle,|}" style="width :300px" alt="paris">
    <div class="card-titile">
        {{post.title}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-text">
        <p>Get details Click find more</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class=" btn btn-success"> Find More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot this really helped me @mike